# How to hide Apache server IP?

Tags: php, apache, ip, hide, anonymous

I'm creating a website which needs do some data gathering anonymously. I ran an Ubuntu server with Apache, and normally when I want to run my script, target websites and servers can determine my server real IP. Is there any solution to hide Apache server IP and use random IPs per each request?

Answer (score 0):

The target website will generally always be able to see your real IP address; you'd have to make each request from a different server, or via a different network connection.

Depending on why and how you're doing this, from where and to whom, it's likely to be an effective way to get banned, sued and/or prosecuted for a [DDoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_DoS) (or some other kind of attack).

Please don't do this.

Comment: It is not a DDoS attack. As I mentioned, I only want to gather some information from different websites.

Comment: It's simply not possible to HIDE your IP, you can get an IP Address Stack and use a huge amount of IP Addresses (if thats required to get unpersonalized responses related).

Notice, if you ignore robots.txt or no-cache and whatever, it's ILLEGAL!

Comment: If it's not an attack, what is the reason for hiding your IP? If you can clarify that, we may be able to help you...